# How does one interface with a C enum using Haskell and FFI?

Tags: haskell, enums, ffi

Let's say charm.c has an enum `key` and a function `get_key()` that returns a `key` type value.

How can I expose a corresponding Haskell `Key` record and function `getKey :: IO Key`?

And how can I do this without manually specifying how every single enum value maps to a Haskell value?

Comment: hsc2hs has a macro for this, but I'd rather just use vanilla Haskell if possible.

Comment: You can't do it in vanilla Haskell without writing it all manually.  hsc2hs and c2hs both have enum hooks, and bindings-dsl uses CPP macros.  These will auto-generate the Haskell type and Enum instance for you, but it's not vanilla Haskell.  Of course you could write it with e.g. c2hs, run the preprocessor, then ship just the resulting Haskell file, but that will often cause problems with e.g. alignment and ptr sizes.

Comment: The reason you need heavyweight tools to do this is that enum constants are a compile-time construct in C — they are not exported symbols which can be retrieved by linking to the library — so discovering the value of enums requires analyzing the C source text.

Comment: @John L: Could you write that as an answer for this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For @KevinReid, here's an example of how to do this with [c2hs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/c2hs).

Given the enum `key` in the file `charm.h` (I have no idea what's in the enum, so I just filled in a few values)

```
typedef enum
  {
    PLAIN_KEY = 0,
    SPECIAL_KEY  = 1,
    NO_KEY = 2
  }
key;

key get_key();
```

You can use c2hs's enum hook like this:

```
{#enum key as Key {underscoreToCase} deriving (Eq, Show)#}
```

To bind to a function, you can use either `call` or `fun`.  `call` is simpler, but doesn't do any marshaling.  Here are examples of both.  The ffi-wrapped `get_key` will return a CInt, so you need to either manually marshal it (if using `call`) or specify the marshaller (if using `fun`).  c2hs doesn't include enum marshallers so I've written my own here:

```
module Interface  where -- file Interface.chs

{#enum key as Key {underscoreToCase} deriving (Eq, Show)#}

getKey = cIntToEnum `fmap` {#call get_key #}

{#fun get_key as getKey2 { } -> `Key' cIntToEnum #}

cIntToEnum :: Enum a => CInt -> a
cIntToEnum = toEnum . cIntConv
```

C2hs will generate the following Haskell from this (slightly cleaned up):

```
data Key = PlainKey
         | SpecialKey
         | NoKey
         deriving (Eq,Show)
instance Enum Key where
  fromEnum PlainKey = 0
  fromEnum SpecialKey = 1
  fromEnum NoKey = 2

  toEnum 0 = PlainKey
  toEnum 1 = SpecialKey
  toEnum 2 = NoKey
  toEnum unmatched = error ("Key.toEnum: Cannot match " ++ show unmatched)

getKey = cIntToEnum `fmap` get_key

getKey2 :: IO (Key)
getKey2 =
  getKey2'_ >>= \res ->
  let {res' = cIntToEnum res} in
  return (res')

cIntToEnum :: Enum a => CInt -> a
cIntToEnum = toEnum . cIntConv

foreign import ccall safe "foo.chs.h get_key"
  get_key :: (IO CInt)

foreign import ccall safe "foo.chs.h get_key"
  getKey2'_ :: (IO CInt)
```

Comment: Seems like enums defined with enum hook now has a default marshaller: https://github.com/haskell/c2hs/wiki/Implementation%20of%20Haskell%20Binding%20Modules.